# Implementing a deletion function for a binary search tree in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to implement a function in C that deletes a node in a binary tree that should (theoretically) take care of three all cases, i.e.:

- Node is a leaf
- Node has one child
- Node has two children

Is there a way to handle the whole deletion function without checking separately each case? As a commenter below noted I do check for a lot of cases and perhaps the whole problem can be addressed recursively by checking for one fundamental case.

I'm particularly interested in the case where I delete a node within the tree that has a parent and itself is a parent of two children nodes.

Both answers below have been useful but I don't think they address the problem in its entirety.

Here's what I have:

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int key;
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

/* functions that take care of inserting and finding a node and also traversing and freeing the tree */
...

void delete(Node *root, int key)
{
    Node *target = find(root, key); // find will return the node to be deleted

    Node *parent = target->parent; // parent of node to be deleted

    // no children
    if (target->left == NULL && target->right == NULL)
    {
        // is it a right child
        if (target->key > parent->key)
            parent->right = NULL;
        // must be a left child
        else
            parent->left = NULL;

        free(target);
    }

    // one child
    else if ((target->left == NULL && target->right != NULL) || (target->left != NULL && target->right == NULL))
    {
        // here we swap the target and the child of that target, then delete the target
        Node *child = (target->left == NULL) ? target->right : target->left;
        child->parent = parent;
        if (parent->left == target) parent->left = child;
        else if (parent->right == target) parent->right = child;
        free(target);
    }
    // two children
      else
    {

        // find the largest node in the left subtree, this will be the node
        // that will take the place of the node to be deleted
        Node *toBeRepl = max(target->left);

        // assign the data of the second largest node
        target->key   = toBeRepl->key;
        target->data  = toBeRepl->data;

        // if new node immediately to the left of target 
        if (toBeRepl == target->left)
        {   
            target->left  = toBeRepl->left;
            Node *newLeft = target->left;
            if (newLeft != NULL) newLeft->parent = target;
        }
        else
        {
            delete(target->left, toBeRepl->key);
            // Node *replParent = toBeRepl->parent;
            // replParent->right = NULL;
        }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

edit: Just to clarify, I'm trying to delete a particular node without touching its subtrees (if there are any). They should remain intact (which I've handled by swapping the values of the node to be deleted and (depending on the case) one of the nodes of its substrees).

edit: I've used as a reference the following wikipedia article:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion
Which is where I got the idea for swapping the nodes values in case of two children, particularly the quote:

> Call the node to be deleted N. Do not delete N. Instead, choose either
>   its in-order successor node or its in-order predecessor node, R.
>   Replace the value of N with the value of R, then delete R.

There is some interesting code in C++ there for the above case, however I'm not sure how exactly the swap happens:

```
else    //2 children
{
        temp = ptr->RightChild;
        Node<T> *parent = nullptr;

        while(temp->LeftChild!=nullptr)
        {
                parent = temp;
                temp = temp->LeftChild;
        }
        ptr->data = temp->data;
        if (parent!=nullptr)
                Delete(temp,temp->data);
        else
                Delete(ptr->rightChild,ptr->RightChild->data);
}
```

Could somebody please explain what's going on in that section? I'm assuming that the recursion is of a similar approach as to the users comments' here.

Comment: You will need to use recursion (or a stack) to handle deletion. i.e. What happens if the children have children? etc.

Comment: I'm only trying to delete a particular node rather than delete the node and its subtrees (which I would do by traversing it recursively in post-order). Or have I misunderstood you?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any "inelegance" in the code, such formatting and commented code is hard to come by. But yes, you could reduce the if-else constructs in your delete function to just one case. If you look at the most abstract idea of what deletion is doing you'll notice all the cases basically boil down to just the last case (of deleting a node with two children).

You'll just have to add a few lines in it. Like after toBeRepl = max(left-sub-tree), check if it's NULL and if it is then toBeRepl = min(right-sub-tree).

So, **Case 1 (No children)**: Assuming your `max()` method is correctly implemented, it'll return `NULL` as the rightmost element on the left sub-tree, so will `min()` on the right sub-tree. Replace your target with the toBeRepl, and you'll have deleted your node.

**Case 2 (One child)**: If `max()` does return `NULL`, `min()` won't, or vice-versa. So you'll have a non-NULL `toBeRepl`. Again replace your target with this new `toBeRepl`, and you're done.

**Case 3 (Two children)**: Same as Case 2, only you can be sure `max()` won't return `NULL`.

Therefore your entire `delete()` function would boil down to just the last `else` statement (with a few changes). Something on the lines of:

```
Node *toBeRepl = max(target->left);
if toBeRepl is NULL
{
  toBeRepl = min(target->right);
}

if toBeRepl is not NULL
{
  target->key = tobeRepl->key;
  target->data = toBeRepl->data;

  deallocate(toBeRepl); // deallocate would be a free(ptr) followed by setting ptr to NULL
}
else
{
  deallocate(target);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, however don't I still need to include code that preserves the links between the different nodes? Particularly the node->parent relation? As I'm not sure how this is handled.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using recursion, assuming that you have `null` at the end of your tree, finding null would be the 'go back' or return condition.

One possible algorithm would be:

```
Node* delete(Node *aNode){
  if(aNode->right != NULL)
     delete(aNode->right);
  if(aNode->left != NULL)
     delete(aNode->left);
  //Here you're sure that the actual node is the last one
  //So free it! 
  free(aNode);
  //and, for the father to know that you're now empty, must return null
  return NULL;

}
```

It has some bugs, for sure, but is the main idea. 
This implementation is [dfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) like. 
Hope this helps.

[EDIT] Node *aNode fixed. Forgot the star, my bad.

Comment: No need of a return value if the function returns `NULL` every time. The parameter should be `Node *aNode`

Comment: Thanks Rémi, it is, in fact, a pointer to Node. Forgot the star. 
About the function type, since I'm testing aNode->right to NULL, wich is a pointer to Node, the function should return the 'equivalent NULL'. It could be an integer or a double, but that wouldn't look nice.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how would I go about deleting a tree with two nodes? The point where the values of the parent (to be deleted) and of the children are swapped is my point of concern. My code seems to address that but there are lots of checks for special cases and I was wondering if there's a more fundamental way to handle it.

Comment: Sorry, with two nodes? This case is for a complete binary tree, with as many nodes as you want. 
If you are asking for the case where you only want to delete a certain node with a certain key, you can do that exactly the same way but instead of just NULL, you test the children for the key too, and instead of doing the the free right away, you correct the pointers first. 

Hope I made myself clear, got a bit confusing. Sorry.

Comment: Okay, but does this mean that I would still need to check if there's one child, or two etc.? Because as I currently understand the code, this would handle only leaves. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I don't think I understand your question. 
This algorithm travels down the tree and finds its leafs. Since it cleans those leafs, the parents of the leafs that it frees are now new leafs, so it frees them too, and this happens continuously until all the tree is freed. 
Was this your doubt?

Comment: That's the thing I don't want to free the whole tree :) I already have a function for this that traverses the tree in post-order. Imagine I have a node, with two children, who themselves have children. And I want to delete that particular node and not touch the rest. As per the BST deletion rules, I am supposed to find the second largest element within that subtree and assign that element's value to the node intended to be deleted. And then free the second largest element. I've updated my question, hope it clarifies what I'm trying to do :) Thanks very much for your comments!

Comment: Ah! Ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding. 
And is your tree ordered/sorted, in some way, using its keys?

Comment: No problem :) It's ordered as a typical BST, start at the root, left is smaller keys, right is bigger keys :) if you consider this link for example:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Binary_search_tree.svg

Comment: Ah, ok. So you probably want to do a fix down every time you delete a node. That makes your recursive function a bit more complicated. 
Try to look for fix down/up algorithms and if you really don't find anything, just add a comment here. Its a bit of code that I have to write to explain my idea and, right now, I really don't have the time. Also, try to update your question, then maybe someone can help you sooner.
Sorry for not being able to help you more, at least for now. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input anyway :) I have updated the question several times but sadly I've not had additional interest, hopefully at some point someone else will also show interest :)

Answer (score 0):

I finished this a long time ago and I thought it would be good to add a sample answer for people coming here with the same problem (considering the 400+ views this question has accumulated):

```
/* two children */
else
{
    /* find the largest node in the left subtree (the source), this will be the node
     * that will take the place of the node to be deleted */
    Node* source = max(target->left);

    /* assign the data of that node to the one we originally intended to delete */
    target->key   = source->key;
    target->data  = source->data;

    /* delete the source */
    delete(target->left, source->key);
}
```

Wikipedia has an [excellent article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion) that inspired this code.